# Make Excel sheet empty cells read-only using python

Tags: excel, python-2.7, file-upload

I am writing a code where one person can upload a question (in excel sheet form) and other person can download that question and upload his/her answer.

I want to know is there any way through which the empty cells in excel sheet(question) uploaded can be made read only so that the other person who downloads cannot write anything in those blanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **openpyxl** library with read_only option to get the desired goal

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb = load_workbook(filename='large_file.xlsx', read_only=True)
```

For further information:
http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/optimized.html

For installing openpyxl:
http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/

Comment: Actually I have some question marks in some cells where the other person downloading the question need to fill correct values so that can be done by doing read_only=True ??